# Optimization packages for R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Does anyone know of any optimization packages out there for R (similar to NUOPT for S+)?

Comment: downvote for 'this question does not show any research effort'

Comment: I "could" have made this a long question talking about the details of what I needed and how I had investigated linprog and found it wanting.  Or I could just ask a very simple question.  I stand by that decision.  BTW, while I disagree with your reasons for downvoting me, at least you had the decency to give a reason.  Thank you for your courtesy.

Comment: If you'd told us where you had looked then that would have shown some research effort - even a simple "i searched google or cran for ' optimisation' " would have helped. We shouldn't have to point people to cran task views... And if you'd found linprog wanting, why accept the answer that says "I've used linprog"?

Comment: It appears 3rd in google search under "linear optimization r", meaning we should be practical about it and use it as a reference for future searchers.

Answer (score 21):

R has many, many packages for optimization; check the CRAN Task view on Optimization: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html. Of course, for nonlinear programs, there is `optim()`, which is standard and includes Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno's algorithm, and Nelder-Mead. It's a good first start.

Answer (score 8):

Try [lpSolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/R.htm) with R.

A simple example:

```
# Maximize 
#   x1 + 9 x2 +   x3 
# Subject to: 
#   x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3 <= 9
# 3 x1 + 2 x2 + 2 x3 <= 15
f.obj <- c(1, 9, 3)
f.con <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
f.dir <- c("<=", "<=")
f.rhs <- c(9, 15)

lp("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)
lp("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)$solution
```

Answer (score 8):

you should also try the [Rglpk](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rglpk/index.html) package solve LP problems with [GLPK (GNU Linear Programming Kit)](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/).

An example:

```
## Simple linear program.
## maximize:   2 x_1 + 4 x_2 + 3 x_3
## subject to: 3 x_1 + 4 x_2 + 2 x_3 <= 60
##             2 x_1 +   x_2 +   x_3 <= 40
##               x_1 + 3 x_2 + 2 x_3 <= 80
##               x_1, x_2, x_3 are non-negative real numbers

obj <- c(2, 4, 3)
mat <- matrix(c(3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2), nrow = 3)
dir <- c("<=", "<=", "<=")
rhs <- c(60, 40, 80)
max <- TRUE

Rglpk_solve_LP(obj, mat, dir, rhs, max = max)
```

R output:
(Note that `$status` an integer with status information about the solution returned. If the control parameter canonicalize_status is set (the default) then it will return 0 for the optimal solution being found, and non-zero otherwise. If the control parameter is set to FALSE it will return the GLPK status codes).

```
$optimum
[1] 76.66667

$solution
[1]  0.000000  6.666667 16.666667

$status
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 7):

Linprog, mentioned by Galwegian, focuses on linear programming via the simplex algorithm. In addition you may be interested in [fPortfolio](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fPortfolio/) if you are doing portfolio optimization.

Answer (score 4):

I have used [linprog](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/linprog/index.html) for linear problems in the past.

Comment: +1 and thanks a lot.  I haven' touched any optimization stuff since my TurboPascal days.  There were a whole bunch of other optimization packages listed in the packages page (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/).

Answer (score 4):

Another package is [ompr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ompr/index.html). An advantage of this package is there are many solvers that can be used and `binary`, `continuous`, `integer` all variables can easily be added. A simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)


model <-  MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x1, type = "integer") %>%
  add_variable(x2, type = "integer") %>%
  set_bounds(x1, lb = 0) %>%
  set_bounds(x2, lb = 0) %>%
  set_objective(x1 - x2, "max") %>%
  add_constraint(x1 + 2*x2 <= 150) %>%
  add_constraint(x1 >= 30) %>%
  add_constraint(x2 >= 40)
```

Solving with `glpk`:

```
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
result <- solve_model(model, with_ROI(solver = "glpk", verbose = TRUE))

get_solution(result, x1)
get_solution(result, x2)
```

It can also be solved with other solvers like `symphony` where the `gap_limit` can be set in case the problem is complex and will take many iterations to converge:

```
library(ROI.plugin.symphony)
result <- solve_model(model, with_ROI(solver = "symphony",
                                      verbosity=-1, gap_limit=1.5))
```

Answer (score 3):

I like Gurobi. It's very expensive for a license, but it can be obtained through many universities. See here http://www.gurobi.com/products/modeling-languages/r

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on the [NLoptr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/nloptr.pdf)  package. It has quite an extensive documentation with examples and lots of algorithms to choose from, depending what problem you are trying to resolve (etc. linear, non-linear, constraint)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally  inject a dynamic momentum in nlopt or any optimizer, involving inertia and viscosity. Does not seem available in .R